# Why the Sampler doesn't gets executed after correlating by the previous Sampler?

Tags: jmeter, correlation

I have the following situation:

There are two Samplers.

I used the Regular Expression Extractor in Sampler No. 1 to extract a parameter from the URL, and used it in the URL of Sampler No. 2

The parameter is extracted successfully, I checked through Debug Sampler. But I see, **the Sampler No. 2 is not executed**.

No error/warning occurred. Simply, the 2nd Sampler is not executed. And If I do not correlate the 2nd Sampler, it gets executed.

Why, is it so. Any ideas ?

Comment: Is it possible for you to share screenshots of your jmeter test? That may provide more details to understand our problem.

Comment: Extremely sorry, I could not share screenshot because the Stackoverflow not allowing to post any images as I'm newbie :)

Answer (score 0):

Check jmeter.log for errors and show the structure as text of your test plan using something like:

```
Test Plan
|
\--Thread Group
     |
     \---Sampler 1
```